# Are classes of objects inherent or subjective?

Tags: classification

When I see a cat, I consider it a cat in my head even though it is technically also a four legged animal, an animal, a pet, a cute animal, etc. Despite belonging to many of these classes, there’s one that jumps out at me when I see a cat: the cat.

Since it feels most natural to represent a cat as a cat, does this mean that the class “cat” is a class that is mind independently the most natural class for that object or is this subjective and due to human psychology?

My second question is do human beings share the same class representation of objects? Sure, almost everyone would look at a cat and think “cat”. But if I’m looking at a person, I might think “woman”, another might think “old woman”, another might think “tall person”, etc. How are these distributed or is this more of a psychology question? What causes these classes to come about in our heads?

Comment: For a coyote, the class that would jump out when seeing a housecat is probably "food". For a mouse, it would be "death bringer". For a space alien it might be "hairy bag of dirty water". So, whose mind gets to decide?

Comment: This seems very similar to an earlier question of yours: [Are there categories that are more natural than others?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/108706/are-there-categories-that-are-more-natural-than-others) Similar to that question, I'd say the "most natural" category is a combination of specificity, familiarity and function, and there isn't much objective there.

Comment: See [Universals](https://iep.utm.edu/universa/).

Comment: Groupings of mammal species are pretty universal. A cat is a cat and a dog is a dog and an elephant is an elephant. But try to translate bird names between languages and you'll immediately be confronted to the completely different arbitrary groupings that different cultures arrived at. What's a mocking jay in French? What's a rouge-gorge in English?

Comment: See https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/natural-kinds/

Answer (score 5):

What you are talking about are called *universals*.

To know *what* something is (here, that some concrete thing you've encountered is a *cat*) is to know its *form*. The form of a thing is that which causes it to be what it is. By "cause", I do not mean *efficient cause*, but what is called the *formal cause*. The form is the principle by which a thing is what it is, by which it is the *kind* of thing it is. Here, you've identified the thing as a *Cat*. In the case of a ball made of bronze, the *Sphericity* is the form that causes the ball to be what it is (a ball; the bronze is the *material cause*); if you hammer the ball into a cube, you have changed *what* the thing in question is.

Of course, the judgement you are making in your mind is something like "this thing is a Cat", where "this thing" is the subject, and "Cat" is the predicate. But how does this predicate come be to? It's not "out there", in the world. You didn't *see* it. The form *Cat* isn't what you've encountered, but some concrete instance. The predicate exists in your intellect, but how did it get there? The key is *abstraction*. This is the essential function of the intellect. Abstraction is the intellectual power by which the form (or essence, nature) of a thing can be separated from a thing, as made available in the senses, and sustained apart from any particular objects that instantiate it. This is a very unique property of intellects, as any other occurrence of form in the world is in the concrete things that instantiate it themselves. You never encounter forms in the real. You never see *Cat*, only this case or that cat. Or, if you like, this triangle, or that triangle, but never *Triangularity* as such.

The features of the instance in question are called *accidents*. Now, the form I mentioned above is known as the *substantial form* (as integral wholes, like individual cats, in the world are what philosophers call substances). But *accidental form* is all that cannot be instantiated as such. Red fur, blue eyes, long hair, even having four paws or a heart - these are accidents. Why? Because while you can instantiate cats as such, you cannot instantiate "red fur", or just "red", as such, only as part of some substance (someone might object that you can have red fur on your sofa that exists apart from a cat; this is true, but it is no longer fur as such, but something that *was* fur, just like a severed hand is no longer a hand, because it no longer functions as a hand). Those accidents that follow necessarily from the nature of the substantial form are called *properties*. For some time, philosophy has become rather loose and sloppy with this word, using it to mean *any* kind of accidental feature, but traditionally, a property was something *proper* to something by virtue of the kind of thing that it is. So while red fur is not a property, just an attribute, having a heart or four paws are arguably properties, because it is essential to what a cat is.

Of course, just having a bag of attributes or properties doesn't help us much. They must inhere in some whole, and the most important thing you can know about something is *what* it is. Is it the *what* of a thing that provides the ground by which we can make sense of all the characteristics of that thing. So it makes sense that the *what* is what is intellectually most prominent or primary. "Red" or even "red fur" by themselves don't help you understand what you've encountered.

However, you might object: "But wait, I don't always know what a thing is! But I can see its features!" Yes. When you encounter something for the first time, you may not have a good understanding of the nature of the thing. This is true. But you do have *some* understanding, however minimal, which is developed the more you observe and interact and study it. When I say that it makes sense that the essence should come to mind first, I do not mean to say it is the first thing you encounter. Note what I wrote earlier, that we abstract from particulars *as given to use in the senses*. Sense perception is prior to abstraction, or else you would not have anything to abstract from. And what we sense are the accidents, as essence is not something we sense as such, but something we abstract from what is sensed. So we come to know the essence through a things accidents. The whole is known before its parts or features as such, which are abstracted. Thus, there is never a moment when you judge "I see red fur" full stop. Rather, the senses, encounter a whole (the cat), and the intellect is where the judgement you spoke of, e.g., "oh, look, a cat" and "this cat has red fur", is occurring. The world is only made *known*, not merely sensed, by the intellect. There is never a moment when you merely sense and then judge, as judgement is intellectual and thus already past the point when abstraction has already occurred.

Comment: Abstraction is why there are 400 programming languages, each developed by sincere people who thought that they were *really getting it* right *this time*. There is no right, because abstraction is inherently arbitrary. If people understood this, it would be a better world. (and there would be fewer programming languages)

Comment: Beware of your sense data like theory as existence may precede essence... Do you really think the judgment of "oh, look, a cat" and "this cat has red fur" is occurring are unique intellectual which a cat doesn't have?...

Answer (score 2):

Objects have multiple properties, so you can classify objects in multiple ways according to their properties. Whether one classification 'jumps out' rather than another, depends in part upon the object and on the observer. My wife is a horticulturalist, so when she walks around a nursery in pursuit of a new purchase the classifications that will 'jump out' to her as she surveys the items on offer will, I am sure, be more specific than the general 'plants' classification which is the only one to jump out to my ignorant mind as I look around. I think it is reasonable to suppose that the factors at play here include:

The extent to which the different properties of the object are apparent to the observer.

Their relative importance to the observer.

The extent to which a particular property of an object is fundamentally associated with the nature of a class of objects. For example, having three straight sides is the essence of a being a triangle, so if you see a yellow triangle you are more likely to think of it as a triangle than as a yellow polygon.

Comment: Bees can see in ultraviolet, and they seem unusually fixated on pollen compared to myself.